# fixed div with content inside scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, fixed

im loosing my mind here...

im trying to make the following:
a fixed div always stays appearing in the page, nothing dificult here, but inside this div i need to put some content that will be scrolling along with the rest of the site, note that the content has NOT his own scrollbar, its need to scroll together with the site, with the main scrollbar of the window...

I already try to make another div inside the fixed div with all the position atributes, with no sucess.
so far:

```
    .furosimg {
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 181px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index:9;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 470px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.furosimg .furosone {
    position: relative !important;
    width: 181px;
    height:900px;
    background:url(../images/topbg.png) center repeat-y;

}
```

any advices?

thanks!

Comment: I couldn't exactly understand you... something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/d8pRs/ or what ??

Comment: no, in this example the red content has his own scrollbar, i need an automatic scroll with the rest of the page, do you get it?

Comment: when the user scroll down the page, the content inside the red div will be scrolling, BUT the red div will stay fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example...all you gotta do is take the amount of window/document/body has scrolled and scroll the fixed element.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rgH56/4/

**CODE**

```
var f= document.getElementById('fi');

window.onscroll = function(){
    f.scrollTop=document.body.scrollTop;
}
```